# Can't Connect to my Own Site But Other Users Can

Tags: connections

Edit: I just as of the time of this edit have tried to go onto the site and it works now. I know that means my issue is resolved but it would still be nice to know what might have gone wrong that caused this issue. I did not change anything it just all of a sudden worked again, it just isn't making much sense to me.

I for some reason can't connect to my own website. I was on it 20 minutes ago and it was working fine, then I go to load up another page and boom I get the Chrome Error Message:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to sitexyz@xyz.com

I have confirmed that other users can connect to it and I have been able to connect to it via proxy.

I have checked the .htaacess and my ip is not blocked. I have checked my cpanel and, my ip is not blocked. I have tried to flush my dns to see if that would help. I also tried clearing my cache just in case.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might the issue be?

Regards,
Fogest

Comment: Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles Yes same issue I still can't connect.

Comment: Have you contacted your isp's support to check that they haven't blocked your ip. I've had this happen to me. Also try getting a new IP from your ISP...

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I don't understand what would have been blocked? I don't see why my ip would be blocked.

Comment: In my case I suspect it was using a crawler to look for broken links, but my hosting provider were not very helpful about it. Most ISP's (those who supply your home internet connection) will be able to describe a procedure that will get you a new IP - that's the only thing I can see that would cause this kind of thing.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles So are you saying I'm being blocked from connecting to it by my isp or that the site is blocking my ip?

Comment: If you can get to other sites, just not your own I'm saying it's possible that your hosting company is blocking your IP address. If you're using a laptop - try another internet connection to test.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles Check my new edit in op. I did not change anything  yet now it works a day later.

Comment: I'd love to know exactly what caused it myself!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem several years ago where I used a full url for my PHP includes, and it was triggering the server firewall. It only blocked me, and was especially problematic when I was trying to run a sitemap tool.

Comment: This actually could be why. I was actually editing a Wiki page on the site when this happened. When installing MediaWiki it told me about some issue that involved PHP. I hope it was a one time issue.

Comment: I just got the issue again! So I guess this is not resolved. I never even went to the wiki but I guess that means something in general is wrong. Is there anyway to fix this or is it just the host?